# why it always come to catch block and not performing the line "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();"

Tags: asp.net

here is my code

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string constr = @"Data Source=ADMIN\LOCALHOST;Initial Catalog=maha;Integrated Security=True";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {

            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            string query = "Insert into [dbo].[student] ([ID],[NAME],[DOB],[GENDER]) Values ('@id','@name','@dob','@gender')";

            Label3.Text = "execute";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", TB1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TB2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", TB3.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", rm);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
    }

}

protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try 
    {
        string constr = @"Data Source=ADMIN\LOCALHOST;Initial Catalog=maha;Integrated Security=True;";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            string query = "Update [dbo].[student] set [ID]=@id,[NAME]=@name, [DOB]=@dob," +
                                "[GENDER]=@gender Where [ID]=@id";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", TB1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TB2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", TB3.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", rm); 
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();          
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
    }   
}
```

Comment: What is the Exception in the catch block ?

Comment: Because it might crash on `con.Open()` or somewhere else ? Please use breakpoints and follow your instructions to see where it crash and WHY.

Comment: actually my error is occurring while converting the TB3.Text into date format? because in my database the dob datatype is date. now I am using  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", DateTime.Parse(TB3.Text)); but still their is an error  "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: So your problem is not execution, but conversion between string and datetime. What datetime format are you using? Try var success = DateTime.TryParse(TB3.Text);

Answer (score 0):

Refer this coding. if any doubt let me know

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", DateTime.Parse( TB3.Text)));
```

Comment: string sr = TB3.Text;
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
dt = DateTime.ParseExact(sr, "yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);  I tried your method also. but it still shows same error.                                                                                                                  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", dt);

Comment: System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)                                                                  This error is coming

Comment: In my database the datatype of dob is "date". In web form input is taken through dateTimePicker and selected date is display in textbox

Comment: just try this one. date format yyyy-mm-dd or yyyy/mm/dd. No need to time. If you have any doubt let me know